# How to set a default value for an optional date argument within a typed function?

Tags: python, mypy

```
from datetime import date

def my_func(start_date: date) -> None:
    print(start_date)
```

How to pass a default value to `start_value` while simultaneously adhere to `mypy` rules and doesn't provide a function in a function signature at the same time?

If I were to do `start_date: date = "2020-12-31"` `mypy` will rightly claim the following error:
Incompatible default for argument "start_date" (default has type "str", argument has type "date")

On the other hand, if I were to provide `start_date: date = date(2020,12,31)`, I am performing a function call in an argument default. This could lead to unforeseen consequences as this function call will be executed once the function gets parsed, not when it's actually called.

So, what are my possibilities to provide a default `start_date`?

Comment: _"This could lead to unforeseen consequences as this function call will be executed once the function gets parsed, not when it's actually called"_ ... how is that a problem?  You are providing a specific date as a default

Comment: `date=None` then check for `None`

Comment: @Anentropic It is simply not good practice to pass a function as default argument. For example, ``flake8-bugbear`` will result in an error when doing this.

Comment: @PeterWood This would make ``mypy`` to fail as ``None`` is not of type ``date``.

Comment: @Andi it's only bad practice if you expect the function call to give a different default value each time the function is called, clearly not the case here.  Anyway, `flake8-bugbear` gives the solution in the description of their linting rule: _"If this is intended, assign the function call to a module-level variable and use that variable as a default value."_

Comment: @Anentropic Well, a date can change between parsing the function and calling it. Anyway, using a module variable is a workaround that makes ``mypy`` and ``flake8-bugbear`` happy.

Comment: @Andi no, the date can't change.

Comment: @PeterWood No? What if the function gets parsed before midnight while it gets called after midnight and you expect the date to be the new date? Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Andi  `date(2020,12,31)` will always give you the same value

Comment: Ah yeah, that's totally true. ``datetime.now()`` would be different. Anyway, it still won't pass ``flake8-bugbear`` without using module variables.